# Frigidaire FRS26R4AQ5 freezer working but fridge is not very cold

Tags: refrigerator

Frigidaire FRS26R4AQ5 freezer working but fridge is not very cold.  Took it apart and coil in the back of the freezer wall is completely frosted over. Does this sound like a defrost issue?  Do I need a multi meter to test?
Thanks

Comment: A multi-meter will narrow down the the problem.  Can be the sensor or the heating coil.  If you can see the coil well(without frost on it), might be able to tell just by eyes if it is broken/burned out.  A meter will prove it or test with frost(frost hiding breaks) on it.

Comment: There shoud be a fan that blows air into the freezer and refrige. Make sure it's working. There's usually a damper between the two so make sure it's not stuck.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a defrost issue.  Depending on system setup, ice buildup could prevent the damper door between the fridge and freezer cabinets from operating.

Comment: After defrosting,  the fan is blowing cool air into the fridge.   Frost kept the fan from running.   Guess I will wait to see if it frosts up again.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Unplug the appliance for a day or two to melt ice that has collected internally. This is likely a defrosting issue or possibly a problem with the seals around one of the doors. Either the defrost cycle isn't allowing enough time to melt internal ice or too much external humidity was allowed inside and froze.